# SFSpeechRecognizer crashes if no microphone input attached in Mac osx

Tags: swift, macos, speech-to-text, avaudioengine

I have implemented Speech to Text in my Mac app. It works perfectly. But if no input device(microphone) is attached in Mac mini, it crashes. Below is the code I have

```
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
        
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
      self.request.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("There has been an audio engine error.")
        return print(error)
    }
    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        print("Speech recognition is not supported for your current locale.")
        return
    }
    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        print("Speech recognition is not currently available. Check back at a later time.")
        // Recognizer is not available right now
        self.delegate?.speechToTextFailed("Speech recognition is not currently available. Check back at a later time.")
        return
    }
    self.onCheckSupportedSpeechToTextLanguage(kUserDefaults?.value(forKey: kChoosedLang) as! String)
    sttTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
        
    })
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
        if let result = result {
            
            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            var lastString: String = ""
            for segment in result.bestTranscription.segments {
                let indexTo = bestString.index(bestString.startIndex, offsetBy: segment.substringRange.location)
                lastString = String(bestString[indexTo...])
            }
            print(" bestString : \(bestString)")
            self.delegate?.speechToTextConvertedText(self.previousString, bestString)
            self.previousString = bestString
            
        } else if let error = error {
            print("There has been a speech recognition error.")
            print(error)
            self.delegate?.speechToTextFailed("There has been a speech recognition error.")
        }
    })
```

if there is no headphone attached in macmini, app crashes at node.installTap(onBus... in above code.

So my question is how can I detect if user has no microphone attached or has some issue and stop app crashing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check input device's channel count.

```
if 0 < AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().inputNumberOfChannels {
  // DO Somthing..
}
```

If there's no input devices available, that API returns 0.

Comment: yeah I did somewhat similar for Mac osx, audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).channelCount, which gave me count.